# "Undirected subgraph of digraph"?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reviewing previous exams of Graph Theory and found this question:

> Consider a strongly connected directed graph G and its underlying
>   undirected graph G*. Prove that λ(G*) ≥ 2.

But I am confused. How can a directed graph have an undirected subgraph? Doesn't "digraph" imply that all edges are directed?

Comment: In $G^*$ you just 'forget' the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "underlying undirected graph," $~G^*$, is just $G$ without the edges having any direction. Since $G$ is strongly connected, every pair of vertices in $G^*$ lies on some cycle in $G^*$. Hence deleting a single edge cannot disconnect the graph. Therefore $\lambda(G^*)\geq2$.